# In play framework 2.4, how to access ssl socket (or ssl client cert)

Tags: https, playframework, playframework-2.4

Using play framework 2.4. I turned on the requiring client certificates by providing my own implementation of SSLEngineProvider. But I just can't find a way to get the client certificate from the controller. I would settle for the underlying socket, but I can't find a way to access that either.

Answer (score 0):

OK. First, there isn't an SSL socket that can be accessed. Netty does its own SSL processing, and doesn't use `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket` for that.

It is not trivial to do what I need, and is not at all supported by Play. The answers I heard about were "we do it through some hooks" (I never saw any code, and my understanding was that this required hacking Play or Netty), or "terminate SSL before it reaches Play" (that one was on top of - "SSL is slow in Play, so you should do it anyway"). Since I create my own SSL engine, I tried associating the engine with the request, but the engine instantiation is done on an I/O thread, where request instantiation is done on a worker's thread, so I couldn't find a way to sync them up.

I've come up with the solution that uses reflection, and would only work on specific (I imagine) versions of Play. It works in 2.4.2. I used IDEA debugger to descend down the live objects to find the information I'm looking for.

```
public class CheckMessage {

    private static Field extract1;
    private static Field extract2;
    private static Field extract3;
    private static Field extract4;
    private static Field extract5;
    private static Field extract6;
    private static Field extract7;
    private static Field extract8;

    public static SSLEngine getSSLEngine() {

        try {

            Http.Request req = Controller.request();

            Field f = extract1;
            if (f == null) {
                extract1 = f = Class.forName("play.core.j.RequestHeaderImpl").getDeclaredField("header");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }

            Object aux = f.get(req);

            f = extract2;
            if (f == null) {
                extract2 = f = aux.getClass().getDeclaredField("rh$1");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            aux = f.get(aux);

            f = extract3;
            if (f == null) {
                extract3 = f = aux.getClass().getDeclaredField("_remoteAddress$1");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            aux = f.get(aux);

            f = extract4;
            if (f == null) {
                extract4 = f = aux.getClass().getDeclaredField("rh$1");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            aux = f.get(aux);

            f = extract5;
            if (f == null) {
                extract5 = f = aux.getClass().getDeclaredField("e$1");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            aux = f.get(aux);

            f = extract6;
            if (f == null) {
                extract6 = f = aux.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("channel");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }
            aux = f.get(aux);

            f = extract7;
            if (f == null) {
                extract7 = f = aux.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("pipeline");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }

            DefaultChannelPipeline dpc = (DefaultChannelPipeline) f.get(aux);

            aux = dpc.get("ssl");
            if (aux == null) { return null; }

            f = extract8;
            if (f == null) {
                extract8 = f = aux.getClass().getDeclaredField("engine");
                f.setAccessible(true);
            }

            return (SSLEngine) f.get(aux);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

    }
}
```